# Projection of a vector's reflection. Find the value of the matrix.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

For the vector **v**, Let **r** be the reflection of **v** in the line
**x** $= t \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$.

[image]

There exists a $2 \times 2$ matrix **R** such that
**r** = **R** **v**
for all 2D vectors **v**. Find **R**.

--

My goal is to find **v** and **r**, or at least representations of them, and then solving for **R** will be pretty easy after that. I have no idea what I should use in the problem to find **v** and **r**, though. Hints would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution using simple ideas. This is based on an example in the great book *How to Solve It* by George Polya in the section "Setting Up Equations."

Let $\mathbf v=(a,b)$, and you want to find $\mathbf r=(p,q)$ which is the reflection of $(a,b)$ in the line $t \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$. Then we know two facts:

1. The line between $(a,b)$ and $(p,q)$ is perpendicular to the given line which has slope $-\frac 12$. This means

$$\frac{q-b}{p-a}=-\frac{1}{-1/2}=2$$

2. The midpoint of the line joining the two points lies on the given line. This means

$$\frac{b+q}2=-\frac 12\cdot\frac{a+p}2$$

You now have two simultaneous linear equations with the two unknowns $p$ and $q$. Solve then with the usual techniques, and you have your answer. Note that you do not "find $\mathbf v$": you take it as given and you find the corresponding $\mathbf r$. The equations doing so tell you your desired matrix.

---

Here is a solution using matrix techniques.

It is clear that any point on the line, such as $(2,-1)$, is reflected onto itself. It is also clear that any vector perpendicular to that line, such as $(1,2)$, is reflected onto its negative, in this case $(-1,-2)$. That means we can use those points as column vectors and set up the matrix equation

$$\mathbf R\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1\\-1 & 2\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1\\-1 & -2\end{pmatrix}$$

Now use any matrix method to find the matrix $\mathbf R$.